# Maximalist program

Tags: training, programs, programming

As you can see it is very hard to find a training program that includes more than just the ''big 3'', 99% of the training programs in existance are copy pasted and are all incredibly minimalistic focused only on raising your bench, squat and deadlift... as if those 3 movements where the only types of strength in existance.

[image]

It really feels like every program in existence is only focused on getting a big chest, big back and huge legs... but what about the other +600 muscles in the body? What about the other sides of fitness? fitness is not just being strong in 3 specific movements.

**What I'm searching is not a program that gets me strong in 3 dogmatic movements but something to literally level up my overall fitness.**

Fitness is a mixture of coordination,flexibility, mobility, speed, endurance, power, general strength, cardiovascular endurance and so on...

Comment: You should look to crossfit. Just my advice will be to learn weightlifting technic from weightlifters, gymnastics from gymnasts. And don't do heroes WOD's every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff Cavalier over on YouTube focuses on doing exactly that. He has a plethora of free videos that may be found there, and he also has a variety of programs which may be purchased on his website. He’s got a background as a physical therapist and believes in training the body both athletically and functionally. Check him out and see if that’s what you are looking for.

- https://www.youtube.com/user/JDCav24
- https://athleanx.com

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @JustSnilloc's very good suggestion about AthleanX, I would also suggest joining Bar Brothers. These are exclusive bodyweight exercises that focus on compound movements, therefore exercising many of the smaller muscles. To complement this, and built holistic fitness, I would include yoga 2-3 times a week for better balance, synchronisation and mind-muscle connection. Actual, authentic yoga, not rubbish like 'HIIT yoga' or 'power yoga' will nourish your body in a very deep way, and counter the excesses of aerobic exercise.